# Is there any way to help a kitten with a URI until I can afford to get him to the vet?

Tags: cats, upper-respiratory-disease

A stray kitten I've been fostering has developed an upper respiratory infection. He has a lot of coughing, occasional sneezing, and runny eyes. We are without power due to the hurricane and I cannot afford to take the kitten to the vet until next week. How can I help him until next week? He has a lot of energy and a very healthy appetite.

Comment: You should try calling local vets. If you explain the situation most vets will be willing to work with you around the financial issue, especially after hurricanes and such since a lot of people might be in similar situations.

Comment: Thanks, but I did cal a few vets. Each of them just gave me suggestions on a different vet I should try who might be willing to work with me on the bill. :(